# Modprobe vfio-pci not working inside VM, what do I do wrong?

Tags: kernel, virtual-machine, dpdk, vfio

I have been trying to load the vfio-pci module into the kernel using the "modprobe vfio-pci" command with no success.

I am a newbie when it comes to low level programming, so I suspect I might be doing something wrong.

What I tried:

1. sudo modprobe vfio-pci // nothing shown in lsmod about vfio
2. modprobe vfio enable_unsafe_noiommu_mode=1 // still, nothing shown in lsmod
3. Added iommu=on as kernel parameter // i am not sure if this is more of a dpdk matter though

Why am I doing this?

I am trying to use DPDK, so I need to load that module as shown [here](https://doc.dpdk.org/guides/linux_gsg/linux_drivers.html).

Environment:

I have tried this inside virtual machines built in VirtualBox, VMWare, Qemu.
It did not work in any of them.
The host is Ubuntu 20.04 and the Guest is Ubuntu 20.04 as well.

CPU information: [print-screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8gGUv.jpg).

edit1: forgot to mention, both modinfo vfio-pci and modinfo vfio display information about those modules, so i guess they are not missing.

Comment: "sudo modprobe vfio-pci // nothing shown in lsmod about vfio" - It seems that functionality of the module is **built-in** into your kernel. In that case, `modprobe` does nothing but returns success. As for `lsmod`, it lists only "real" modules and doesn't print built-in ones.

Comment: Oh it makes sense, thank you so much. I was getting an error when trying something with dpdk and I thought I wasn't loading the module correctly. Should I delete this question? I am not sure how this works.